# Javascript enabling is not working in chrome in htmlunitdriver

Tags: javascript, html, jsoup, htmlunit, htmlunit-driver

I am trying to get data from e-commerce sites by crawling using jsoup. Since I am getting dynamic contents i am using `HtmlUnitDriver`.
But it is returning only empty tags as given below.

I have also enabled javascript by giving the following

```java
HtmlUnitDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver(BrowserVersion.CHROME);
driver.setJavascriptEnabled(true);
```

But still i am getting empty tags, please help me in this.

**NOTE:** I am using chrome browser.

```html
<html>
  <head/>
  <body/>
</html>
```

Comment: You need to `wait`, please look into http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/faq.html#AJAXDoesNotWork

Comment: You mean i have to add wait there, as the htmlunit is still executing it?

Comment: Yes, you need to `wait()` for the background JavaScript to finish

Comment: I am new to this webclient, and can you please give me a full sample showing it.